# I can't install the snap version of GIMP

Tags: 18.04, software-center, snap, gimp, gnome-software

While installing GIMP, Ubuntu Software said that:

> Unable to install "GNU Image Manipulation Program":
>   snap "gimp" has "install-snap" change in progress

[image: Here's the picture]

Comment: Can you reboot and try again, and let us know if you have the same error?

Answer (score 0):

"install-snap" change in progress means that it's installing. It's a graphical bug of gnome-software.

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you resolve this issue?